# How to parse JSON returned by Foursquare

Tags: json, response, foursquare

Ok so I'm trying to parse the data returned by Foursquare for a GET request to return venue details. Here is the section of the response I need to parse:

```
{"meta":{"code":200,"errorType":"deprecated","errorDetail":"Please provide an API version to avoid future errors.See http:\/\/bit.ly\/vywCav"},"response":{"venue":{"id":"4b522afaf964a5200b6d27e3","name":"The Woodville","contact":{"phone":"+442920397859","formattedPhone":"+44 29 2039 7859","twitter":"woodvillelovers"},"location":{"address":"1 - 5 Woodville Rd.","lat":51.49051570871893,"lng":-3.1805795431137085,"postalCode":"CF24 4DW","city":"Cardiff","state":"Wales","country":"United Kingdom"}
```

And here is my code to parse and display this info:

```
$json = json_decode($response);
foreach ($json->response->venue as $result)
{
    echo $result->name.' - '.$result->address.' '.$result->city."<p />";
 }
```

The error I'm getting is that the line in the foreach is 'trying to get property of non-object'. What am I doing wrong here? Can't seem to see the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess since I do not know php but maybe it is because the address and city do not fall under venue but under venue->location.

```
$json = json_decode($response);
foreach ($json->response->venue as $result)
{
    echo $result->name.' - '.$result->location->address.' '.$result->location->city."<p />";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I still get the same error though. I have no idea how to parse this information and it's vital for what I'm doing!